# Post Status to Facebook from Laravel App

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form in side my Laravel application

[image]

When user submit on that form, it will make a post to

`/facebook/status/post`

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/facebook/status/post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form','id' => 'postFbStatus')) !!}

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What's your status?">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt10">Submit Post</button>

{!! Form::close();!!}
```

---

**Route**

```
Route::post('facebook/status/post','FbController@post');
```

---

**Controller**

```
public function post(){

    $fb = App::make('SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk');
    $id =  Auth::user()->account_id;
    $token_oauth = DB::table('tokens')->where('account_id','=',$id)->first();

    try {
        $token = $token_oauth->oauth;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }

    //provide the token
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);

    // Get basic info on the user from Facebook.
    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email');
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }

    // Convert the response to a `Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphUser` collection
    $facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();
    $facebook_id = $facebook_user->id;

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebook_id.'/feed';

    $status = Input::get('status');

    $data                 = [];
    $data['access_token'] = $token;
    $data['message']      = $status;
    $data['from']         = env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID');
    $data['to']           = $facebook_id;
    $data['caption']      = 'Caption';
    $data['name']         = 'Name';
    $data['description']  = 'via demo.PHPGang.com';

    dd($data);

    CURL::POST($url,$data);




}
```

---

**Data Array**

```
array:7 [▼
  "access_token" => "CAAO8ZBRshTC8BAOIZBlv7ZAZBOtc3y9pggTslVkPzhq1AfD2ihriV2RfAnQVZAQeKuS64rkJvV2YZAE8NrzuCsFpZA6ZB2KEisDYvafd40iflvjhjUFqJ9HpMrDKxSygKoBZAKOkYutVeIxdKsGh3PZAHQHHKv01JFrQl7x7HZBZA1wr3mSm2Dt9RHWkggrdIJ3rumFTPVRZAUKVZCYfgZDZD"
  "message" => null
  "from" => "105220301f8177583"
  "to" => "14239698280f3345"
  "caption" => "Caption"
  "name" => "Name"
  "description" => "via demo.PHPGang.com"
]
```

Comment: @Denis Mysenko : I hope you don't mind give me a bit more hint on this facebook post.

Comment: I'm close now, I'm trying to construct an object to post my status. What is the least data, I should provide when posting a status.

Comment: Wait, if I can't even post the status yet, how do I get the status id ?

Comment: Do you know what is my data array should look like ? I updated my post with it.

Comment: if you are using that Facebook package, you don't need to call CURL directly. You could just $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token); $fb->post('/me/feed', [ 'message' => 'Something here', 'caption' => 'Some caption' ]); Also, when you post to users own feed – you can use 'me' alias (/me/feed instead of /user_id/feed)

Comment: @DenisMysenko : If you want, you can answer this one, it seems like you got most of it correct already. :)